# How should I pass a function that runs an external file to be able to use multiprocessing?

Tags: python, windows, function, multiprocessing

I recently saw a module that allows me to run my code simultaneously which happens to be what I need. However, as I was testing with function, I ran into some errors and needed help.

So basically I will need to run a code from an external python script named `genODE`. Basically `genODE` is my simulation file, so it finds the file spec, process it, and generates an output file.

Currently this is my code(Im running this in spyder(anaconda3) btw, in Windows if it helps),

```
import multiprocessing
import time
from astools import generateODEScript as genODE


if __name__ == '__main__':
    
    start = time.perf_counter()

    processes = []
    for niteration in range(26, 31):
        kwargs = {
            'modelfile': f'./models/organism/organism_{niteration}.modelspec',
            'mtype': 'ASM',
            'solver': 'RK4',
            'timestep': '1',
            'endtime': '21600',
            'lowerbound': '0;0',
            'upperbound': '1e-3;1e-3',
            'odefile': f'organism_{niteration}.py'
            
        }
        processes.append(multiprocessing.Process(target=genODE, kwargs=kwargs))

    for process in processes:
        process.start()
    for process in processes:
        process.join()
    end = time.perf_counter()
    print('5 simulations completed in seconds: ', (end-start))
```

Update: Whenever I try to run the script, it said that `generateODEscript() takes 1 to 8 positional arguments but 9 were given`

```
import time
import astools
import multiprocessing

if __name__ == '__main__':
    
    processes = []
    for niteration in range(1, 11):
        kwargs = {
            'modelfile': f'./models/organism/organism_{niteration}.modelspec',
            'mtype': 'ASM',
            'solver': 'RK4',
            'timestep': '1',
            'endtime': '21600',
            'lowerbound': '0;0',
            'upperbound': '1e-3;1e-3',
            'odefile': f'organism_{niteration}.py'
            
        }
    
        start = time.perf_counter()
        with multiprocessing.Pool(processes=5) as pool:
            processes.append(pool.starmap(astools.generateODEScript, kwargs))

    
        end = time.perf_counter()
        print(f'Processes completed in {end-start: .2f}s')
```

Comment: It is best to approach the problem as (producer consumer pattern). first function produces the data and insert it into a queue, then the second function consumes the data from the queue.
In this way: both functions can run independently, you do not wait for the first function to finish to start the second function. see this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67013844/how-to-properly-implement-producer-consumer-in-python

Comment: There's no concurrency here. You start a process then join - i.e., wait for it to finish. Also, are you sure that's the exact error message you're seeing?

Comment: I see you made the output of first function ``` odefile='organism_{niteration}.py' ``` 
should it be csv?

Comment: @MoHuss Nope, it runs as a python code, but it will be converted as .csv output in `runODE`

Comment: @LancelotduLac Then how should I put it to run 30 `genODE` at the same time then 30 `runODE` again?

Comment: @LancelotduLac well not exactly, its `AttributeError: Can't get attribute 'sim' on <module '__main' (built-in)>`

Comment: @JohnSmith No idea why you're getting that error. However I can tell you that you'll need odefile=f'organism_{niteration}.py'

Comment: @LancelotduLac I see, alright

Comment: As an aside, you are creating multiple process instances in a loop that you assign to the same variable `simulation` overlaying the previous value. Then after iterating the loop, you do a single `simulaion.join()`, which joins the *last* process you started and you will be *implicitly* waiting for the other processes to complete before your program can exit. **This make no sense.** Why bother even doing the one call to `join`?

Comment: @Booboo well, I edited the code, I assume it still doesn't make sense, but could you advise me on how I should change it>

Comment: What is your platform (Windows? Linux? Something else?). You are supposed to tag these *multiprocessing*-tagged questions also with your platform. And are you running this from a command line prompt or within some special execution environment?

Comment: @Booboo, oh I didnt know that, Im running from Windows, Im running my script in spyder under anaconda3.

Comment: I am not familiar with spyder, but I know with Jupyter Lab that your worker function, `simulation` in this case, will not be found unless it is imported from an external module. Try doing that by creating module `simulation.py` which will contain function `simulation` and then in your main program do `from simulation import simulation`. Ideally this import as well as the assignments to `p1` and `p2` and the import of module `microprocessing` should be moved to within the `if __name__ == '__main__':` block since your subprocesses do not need to execute these statements.

Comment: Likewise and for the same reason move the definitions of `start` and `end` . The statement `from astools import generateODEScript as genODE` will of course be moved to *simulation.py* as it is not needed by the main process.

Comment: @Booboo does it mean that there will no function here? except for `if __name__ == '__main__':`?

Comment: what if the `simulation` function can be found in `astools` name `genODE`?  do I do `from astools import generateODEScript as genODE` and assign them to p1 and p2? If so, how can I include my arguments in this case, (etc. modelfile, mtype)

Comment: @JohnSmith Yes, if you do as I suggest, then you would have no function definition in your main source file. I repeat that this is just something for you to try to see if it resolves your exception because I do not know if spyder has the same multiprocessing issues that Jupyter Lab (or Notebook) has. We will find out. You can also do away with this `simulation` function altogether and directly specify `genODE` as the *target* argument of the `Process` invocation, but you won't then be printing out 'Running simulation number: ...', which is in `simulation`.

Comment: @Booboo I manage to resolve the attribution error base on your suggestion, Thank you. However, Im getting a new error message which is for the positional arguments, how can I include all 8 positional arguments inside the code? `(modelfile=f'./models/organism/Organism_{niteration}.modelspec', mtype='ASM', solver='RK4', timestep='1', endtime='21600', lowerbound='0;0', upperbound='1e-3;1e-3', odefile=f'organism_{niteration}.py')`

Comment: @JohnSmith See my posted answer.

Answer (score 0):

Here's a framework suggestion for introducing some concurrency to this problem:

```
from concurrent.futures import ProcessPoolExecutor

def genODE():
    pass
def runODE():
    pass
def sim(n):
    print(n)
    genODE()
    runODE()

def main():
    with ProcessPoolExecutor() as executor:
        executor.map(sim, range(1, 31))

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

Leaving it up to OP to "fill in the gaps".

Depending on the OS and/or potential memory constraints, consideration should be given to specifying max_workers=N in the ProcessPoolExecutor constructor

Answer (score 0):

This is a full working example for a solution with producer consumer pattern using queue and multi threaded.

```
from concurrent.futures import ThreadPoolExecutor
from concurrent.futures import as_completed
from queue import Queue
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd


def genODE(itmun):
    dates = pd.date_range('20130101', periods=6)
    pdf = pd.DataFrame(np.random.randn(6, 4), index=dates, columns=list('ABCD'))
    pdf['itmun'] = itmun
    return pdf

def runODE(pdf):
    itnum = pdf['itmun'][0]
    pdf['itmun'] = pdf['itmun'] + 1
    return pdf

def producer(queue, itmun):
    # apply your function to create the data
    data = genODE(itmun)
    # put the data in the queue
    queue.put(data) 

def consumer(queue):
    while not queue.empty(): 
        data = queue.get() 
        # do somework on the data by running your function
        result_data = runODE(data)
        itnum = result_data['itmun'][0]
        result_data.to_csv(f'{itnum}test.csv')
        queue.task_done()
        return result_data 


def main():
    q = Queue() 
    futures = []
    with ThreadPoolExecutor(max_workers=15) as executor:
        for p in range(30):
            producer_future = executor.submit(producer, q, p)
            futures.append(producer_future) 
        for c in range(30):
            consumer_future = executor.submit(consumer, q)
            futures.append(consumer_future)

        for future in as_completed(futures):
            # do something with the result as soon as it is available such as saving or printing or nothing if you already done what you need in runODE()
            print(future.result()) 

if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

Comment: Sorry im still pretty new to this, but may I know whether would my parameters for `genODE` and `runODE` come in? 

Also could you explain it a little more cause its still confusing to me  haha

Answer (score 0):

Since `genODE` takes keyword arguments, you need to pass to `multiprocessing.Process` the *kwargs* argument specifying a dictionary of keyword/value pairs. So to start the two processes that you wanted with `niteration` taking on values 1 and 2:

```py
if __name__ == '__main__':
    import time
    import multiprocessing
    from astools import generateODEScript as genODE

    start = time.perf_counter()

    processes = []
    for niteration in (1, 2):
        kwargs = {
            'modelfile': f'./models/organism/Organism_{niteration}.modelspec',
            'mtype': 'ASM',
            'solver': 'RK4',
            'timestep': '1',
            'endtime': '21600',
            'lowerbound': '0;0',
            'upperbound': '1e-3;1e-3',
            'odefile': f'organism_{niteration}.py'
            
        }
        processes.append(multiprocessing.Process(target=genODE, kwargs=kwargs))

    for process in processes:
        process.start()
    for process in processes:
        process.join()
    print('process completed')
    end = time.perf_counter()
    print(end-start)
```

**Update**

You cannot use method `starmap` if you want to pass keyword arguments that vary; you need to use method `apply_async`.

If your worker function returns values you want to keep, then you need to save and process the `AsyncResult` objects returned by `apply_async`:

```py
import time
import astools
import multiprocessing

if __name__ == '__main__':
    
    start = time.perf_counter()
    with multiprocessing.Pool(processes=5) as pool:
        async_results = []
        for niteration in range(1, 11):
            kwargs = {
                'modelfile': f'./models/organism/organism_{niteration}.modelspec',
                'mtype': 'ASM',
                'solver': 'RK4',
                'timestep': '1',
                'endtime': '21600',
                'lowerbound': '0;0',
                'upperbound': '1e-3;1e-3',
                'odefile': f'organism_{niteration}.py'
                
            }
            async_results.append(pool.apply_async(astools.generateODEScript, kwargs=kwargs))
        results = [async_result.get() for async_result in async_results]
        pool.close()
        pool.join()
    end = time.perf_counter()
    print(f'Processes completed in {end-start: .2f}s')
    print(results)
```

If you don't care about the return value from your worker function and just want to wait for all tasks to complete, then the sequence `pool.close(); pool.join()` is sufficient:

```py
import time
import astools
import multiprocessing

if __name__ == '__main__':
    
    start = time.perf_counter()
    with multiprocessing.Pool(processes=5) as pool:
        for niteration in range(1, 11):
            kwargs = {
                'modelfile': f'./models/organism/organism_{niteration}.modelspec',
                'mtype': 'ASM',
                'solver': 'RK4',
                'timestep': '1',
                'endtime': '21600',
                'lowerbound': '0;0',
                'upperbound': '1e-3;1e-3',
                'odefile': f'organism_{niteration}.py'
                
            }
            pool.apply_async(astools.generateODEScript, kwargs=kwargs)
        # Wait for all submitted tasks to complete:
        pool.close()
        pool.join()
    end = time.perf_counter()
    print(f'Processes completed in {end-start: .2f}s')
```

Comment: Hi, may I know whether its possible to limit the number of processes that I am able to run in parallel?

Comment: If you had N tasks and you wanted them to be accomplished by M processes, where N > M, then you should be using a multiprocessing pool of size M and submitting the N tasks the pool (there are various methods for doing that, which depends on which pool implementation you use). If you are talking about something else, then I have no idea what you are aiming at.

Comment: Will I be able to apply the dictionary of keyword arguments inside the multiprocessing pool?

Comment: Yes, you will be able to.

Comment: When I ran the updated code above, it said that I had given 9 arguments instead of 8, not sure what I did wrongly

Comment: What did the invocation of `multiprocessing.Process` actually look like?

Comment: It runs the Input file in the background and produces an output file, takes around 10 minutes or so, every process would take abt 15-20% of my CPU usage base on Task Manager. Right now I'm trying to get the multiprocessing `pool.map` or `pool.starmap` to work but cant really figure out how to. I even tried using `partial()` to input all the keyword arguments but to no avail

Comment: I just updated the post

Comment: See the **Update** to my answer. You really need to thoroughly familiarize yourself with all the methods of `multiprocessing.pool.Pool`  as to how they work and what type of arguments they take.

Comment: I see, sorry, really new to multiprocessing, only heard recently, will look more into it and try out